# Should I use the Core Text API or draw text API in Quartz?

Tags: ios, core-text

I am new to iOS, and I am going to write a book reader(like [Stanza](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stanza/id284956128?mt=8)) for iOS. But now I am confused by the text related APIs offered by Apple, there's quite a lot of them. I took a look at one of them - Core Text, which seems quite convenient to use. But the problem is that Core Text just does not reuse memory, for drawing a page of text, I have to create an `NSAttributedString`, a `CTFramesetterRef` and a `CTFrameRef`. And after the text is drawn on the screen, those objects are supposed to be released, the memory they occupied just couldn't be reused(or there's a way to reuse those memory?).

So, it looks like memory use of those APIs is not efficient, memory allocation and deallocation happen too frequently.

What I am wishing to do is that I am able cache some context settings, setting them on the context in `drawRect:` when I want to draw some text, and the text is cached in a plain `NSMutableString*`(not an `NSAttributedString*`), later I can append text to the `NSMutableString*` cache.

P.S.: The reason why I use an `NSMutableString*` for cache is that the book, a txt file can be too big to be kept in memory(as far as effective use of memory is concerned), I will always keep a block of text, say several pages in memory, and when the user turns pages, I will read more pages from the txt file and append the text to the cache, of course I will cut those text in the start of the cache when some requirements are met.

The question is: Which Text API should I use and why? or If I have to use Core Text, is it possible to reuse those memory?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the memory. CoreText is good a framework to work with text. You will have to use `CFRelease()` to release the memory acquired. Have a look at the [CoreFoudation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000127i) memory management guide.

Comment: By reuse I mean `no need to release the memory` until the application terminates. like a char array, `char[10]`, you can say, `char[0] = 'a'`, and do something with `char[0]` whose value is `'a'` and later do another assignment `char[0]='b'` and do something with `char[0]` again, whose value now is `'b'`.

Comment: What you say can be done with mutable variants of your objects.I mean Instead of NSAttributedString you can use NSMutableAttributedString.

Comment: But I still can't reuse objects like `CTFrameRef ` and `CTFramesetterRef `, they are always returned from a function when being created, not through being passed as parameter to a function.